# Triple pole triple throw relay

Tags: arduino, motor, relay, ac

I have a turntable which rotates cw and ccw. This turntable is rotated by AC synchronous motor of 230V. I want to be able to rotate the turntable with Arduino.  For this reason I need to control the switch (toggle switch) of the turntable. This switch is connected with motor with three wires, one of the wires is for cw rotation the other ccw; the middle one is common or no rotation.

Problem is that I need to make sure that only one direction of the rotation will work on the same time otherwise motor may be damaged. So I need to have some restriction not only in program but also in electrical components.

I am thinking if there is any relay that can be connected with both rotations and also with common. Or any other idea how to realize this would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about that I meant to say SPDT switch not DPDT switch. My answer has been updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your objective is to allow one of several wires to be powered at a time, while ensuring that there will never be more than one powered.

A simple way to achieve this is to feed power into the common contact of an SPDT switch or relay.  The normally-closed contact will power one output.  The normally-open output will feed the common contact of the next switch (relay).  The normally-open contact of the second switch will power a second output, while the normally-closed contact will feed power to a third switch.  This pattern may be cascaded as deeply as desired.

Using this approach, activating the first switch will power the first output and prevent any others from being powered.  Activating the second switch *when the first is not activated* will power the second.  Activating the third switch *when the first two are not activated* will power the third, etc.

If one is using relays, it would be possible to use other approaches to ensure that while e.g. relay 2 is activated, any attempt to activate relay 1 would be ignored (rather than having relay 1 "take over"), but such approaches would add complexity.  The approach described should be simple to implement and very robust.

Comment: If I use relays to connect with Arduino, how can I give power to second relay if the first one is closed ?
Sorry for my questions but I am new in electronics and I have never used relays before

Answer (score 0):

I would take apart the switch for the motor. Add a SPDT switch before it. Then supply power to the switch through the SPDT switch on one end. On the other end go to your microcontroller. The switch will now be manual or microcontroller controlled motor. This will allow you to safely control the motor manually since moving the SPDT switch will disconnect the microcontroller. I would give you a diagram but I am on my phone and don't have the schematic for the switch.

Comment: But in this way that you are suggesting i will control only two throws, but i need to have three throws cc, ccw and com

Comment: If you power the manual switch through the SPDT on one side and on the other side you power the microcontroller you will be able to control three from the microcontroller and 3 from the original switch which will still be hooked up.

Answer (score 0):

The motor has three wires and this means common can always remain connected. CW and CCW can never be connected together and, it seems appropriate that a single pole changeover contact is used. To disable both directions and allow free spinning of the motor/turntable, add another relay that open circuits the contact on the previous relay so, in effect is is either connected to or not to the AC supply.

1st relay controls direction, 2nd relay controls on/off.

Comment: Thank you firstly, and are you are saying for example I can connect arduino with common of one SPDT relay which controls on/of and than NO of that relay will be connected with the common of another SPDT relay which controls direction, am I right ?

Comment: @ilirvg Yes that's what I'm saying but the arduino doesn't connect to the relay contact - it activates the coil that moves the contact - you'll probably need a transistor to drive the relay coil too.

Answer (score 0):

The relays are shown in the de-energized position, and this should work with the turntable switch in the OFF position.

[image]