# Connecting common of relay with main cable of 240VAC

Tags: arduino, relay, ac, mains

I trying to control my turntable switch with Arduino. This is a toggle switch with 3 wires one wire is for CW rotation the other one is for CCW and the other cable is main with 240VAC. I am using [this relay shield](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Relay_Shield_V2.0); from this shield I am using two relays with this this connection idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbho6f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So basically one relay is controlling on/off and the other relay will control rotation in CW and CCW. For now I have tried this connection with two 12V LEDs and it's working fine. But now that I need to use my turntable, I think I should connect common of first relay with the main of 240V AC and I am not sure if I can do this or not (how safe it is).

What am I trying to achieve is better described here: [Triple pole triple throw relay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/120786/triple-pole-triple-throw-relay/120803?noredirect=1#comment239336_120803)

Answer (score 3):

The relays on the shield you linked are rated for 7A at 250V AC, but I don't think the relay shield itself is designed for that.

[image: Relay Shield]

The [product page](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Relay_Shield_V2.0#Cautions) states:

> **Cautions**:
>
> Place 2 layers of electrical tape on the top of the Arduino's USB connector. This will prevent the relay shield from making contact. **Do not operate voltage more than 35V DC.**

*(Emphasis mine.)*

The [datasheet](http://www.helishun.com/secure/pdt/hls8-t73.pdf) for the relays on that board ([Heli Shun HLS8L-DC5V](http://www.helishun.com/hls8-t73.html)) show that the primary coil is 5V 0.36W:

[image: Datasheet]

Note that the contact ratings section specifies 250V AC / 30V DC. This immediately makes me question the difference between the relay datasheet (30V DC) and the shield product page (*35V* DC).

Since you're using AC, this discrepancy might just be a side note. The shield product page doesn't even mention AC for the switching voltage, it just repeats the 35V DC max switching voltage.

[image: Shield Specifications]

Based on this, I don't think I would connect 240V AC, because it may be that the PCB isn't designed with the necessary voltage isolation.

Further, since you're not experienced working with mains voltage, which can be ***extremely dangerous,*** I don't recommend doing so without the assistance of a professional.